# How to insert values from list into string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I gave a list with values: `["a", "b", "c"]`. and I have a string: "SELECT FROM db". I would like to paste all values from my list into that string after SELECT. so desired result is: "SELECT "a", "b", "c" FROM db". How could I do that?

Comment: The naive way would be to use a template string and format it.
The secure way is to use a secure SQL composition function from a library of your choosing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use string concatenation and string formatting:

Code:

```
letters = ["a", "b", "c"]

text = "SELECT FROM db"

text = text.split()

letters = ", ".join(letters)
text = f"{text[0]} {letters} {' '.join(text[1:])}"
print(text)
```

Output:

```
SELECT a, b, c FROM db
```

Comment: This is how SQL injections are born.

Comment: @RichardNeumann I understand that SELECT is an SQL statement/query, but there is no indication that the code actually uses SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values in the column list are sanitized, you can use string interpolation:

```
columns = ["a", "b", "c"]
query = "SELECT {0} FROM db".format(','.join(columns))
print(columns)
```

**Update:** note that you should sanitize query parameters to prevent SQL injection. For example:

```
columns = ["a", "b", "c"]

def sanitize(input):
    """
    sanitize user input to prevent SQL injection.
    change it with a more robust sanitizion policy / library.
    """
    sanitized = []
    for i in input:
        if i.isalpha():
            sanitized.append(i)
    return sanitized

columns = sanitize(columns)
query = "SELECT {0} FROM db".format(','.join(columns))
print(query)
```

Output:

```
SELECT a,b,c FROM db
```

Comment: This is how SQL injections are born.